# nHibernate Share References?

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, exception

I'm getting the following exception when saving an object:

> Found shared references to a collection

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: It would be cool if you could mark any of the provided answers as a solution or write down your own solution if you've found any.

Answer (score 4):

In theory it means that you have 2 records which contain the same reference to another object. At the database level this is most likely a weak entity, however at the code level this is likely to be represented as a collection.

Have you copied another records collection?
E.g.

```
Blog blog1 =  Blog.Find(1);
Blog blog2 = new Blog();
blog2.Entries =  blog1.Entries;
blog2.Save();
```

This code is for ActiveRecords, but as it is built on top of nHibernate the underlying principles are the same.

The interesting thing when i came across this issue was that the collection it referred to was incorrect. It was a different one.

If this is your issue try iterating through each item and assigning it to the new collection in stead. E.g.

```
Blog blog1 =  Blog.Find(1);
Blog blog2 = new Blog();

foreach (BlogEntry entry in blog1.Entries)
   blog2.Entries.Add(entry);
blog2.Save();
```

Answer (score 3):

[quick google says](http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2273553)

```
  rel   Group n --- 1 User
         m             ^
         |             | inh
         |  rel        |
         --------- n Member
```

> rel stands for relation (association)
>   inh stands for inheritance
>
> The exception is thrown after Member
>   objects have successfully been created
>   and then have been read from the
>   database. After the last Member object
>   was read the transaction is committed
>   but this fails.

what do your mappings look like?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reference to any of the objects in the collection somewhere else? Another session, possibly, or even within the same session in another object? Make sure that when you access hibernate, you are controlling the ONLY reference to those objects within any hibernate session.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this error occurs when you have a joined-subclass mapping where an inherited property is mapped in both the super- and sub-class. Say you have these objects:

```
public class Being
{
    public string DnaSequence { get; protected set; }
}

public class Animal : Being
{
    public IList<Animal> Relatives { get; protected set; }
}

public class Human : Animal
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
}
```

In your `Human` mapping, it's important that you **don't** map the `Relatives` property. In a joined-subclass mapping, you should only map properties that are unique to the level in the hierarchy you are mapping:

1. For `Being`, you only map the `DnaSequence` property.
2. For `Animal`, you only map the `Relatives` property.
3. For `Human`, you only map the `Name` property.

If you, by accident, map `Relatives` in the `Human` mapping, NHibernate will throw "Found shared references to a collection".